# How to redirect to a different location using GDB?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Basically I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[100];
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
    printf("Buf congains: %s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I have debugged it, Below is what happening:

executing shell:

```
run `perl -e 'print "A"x100'`
```

1. Copy `argv[1]` to $rbp
2. after executing `strcpy()` copy argv[1] from $rbp to `$rsp/buf`
3. print data from $rsp

Stack print while breakpoint on line `printf()`

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffebd8) at main.c:7                                                         
7           printf("Buf congains: %s\n", buf);                                                                       
(gdb) x/50x $rsp                                                                                                     
0x7fffffffea70: 0xffffebd8      0x00007fff      0x00400372      0x00000002                                           
0x7fffffffea80: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141                                           
0x7fffffffea90: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141                                           
0x7fffffffeaa0: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141                                           
0x7fffffffeab0: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141                                           
0x7fffffffeac0: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141                                           
0x7fffffffead0: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141                                           
0x7fffffffeae0: 0x41414141      0x00007f00      0x79529b00      0x7349452f                                           
0x7fffffffeaf0: 0x00000000      0x00000000      0xf7a35ec5      0x00007fff                                           
0x7fffffffeb00: 0x00000000      0x00000000      0xffffebd8      0x00007fff                                           
0x7fffffffeb10: 0x00000000      0x00000002      0x004005f6      0x00000000                                           
0x7fffffffeb20: 0x00000000      0x00000000      0xd23fb797      0xacdf42c3                                           
0x7fffffffeb30: 0x00400500      0x00000000
```

**Question:** Basically what I want is to modify data of a different memory location and point the `buf` to that location.

for example modify `0x7fffffffeb20` in $rsp using `set {char[5]}0x7fffffffeb20 = "BCDE"` and then set the data of `0x7fffffffeab0` to point to `0x7fffffffeb20` so when $rip is executing `0x7fffffffeab0` address, it should point to read extra data from `0x7fffffffeb20`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does `run perl -e 'print "A"x100'` have to do with this C program? Is `run` the name of the executable?

Comment: `buf` is not a variable, you can't change where it points to. It's a fixed stack offset, and the debugging symbol `buf` just tells `gdb` where to find the contents.

Comment: @barmar `perl -e 'print "A"x100'` mean to print `A` 100 times, so rather than doing: `run AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`, you simply do `perl -e 'print "A"x100'` it's perl script for ease of access

Comment: If you want `AAA...` to be the argument to the program, you need to use `run $(perl -e 'print "A"x100')`. The way you wrote it, `argv[1]` is just the word `perl`.

Comment: Are you trying to create a buffer overflow? `char buf[100]` isn't big enough for 100 A + null terminator.

Comment: @barmar, sorry, there is actually an extra ` but apparently stackoverflow doesn't like it there!!!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254364/how-to-print-backtick-inside-backticks for how to do it. But it's easier if you just use an indented code block instead of inline code.

Answer (score 1):

`buf` is not a variable, so you can't change it dynamically. If you want to be able to change the address, add a pointer variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[100];
    char *bufp = buf;
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
    printf("Buf contains: %s\n", bufp);
    return 0;
}
```

Then you can change the value of `bufp` after `strcpy()` and it will use that.

```
(gdb) set variable bufp = 0x7fffffffeb20;
```

BTW, you're causing a buffer overflow with your 100 A's. `buf[100]` only has room for 100 characters, but you need `buf[101]` to allow room for the 100 letters and the trailing null byte. So the `strcpy()` results in undefined behavior.

If you're studying buffer overflows and shellcode, this may be intentional, but otherwise you should fix it.

Comment: I did as you said, but the output is that `bufp` is located at `0x7fffffffea80` and if I do `x/200x $rsp` and locate `0x7fffffffea80`, its content is the same as `buf` contains `A` 100 times, so once again I am going to have to ask: `How to modify pointer location to point to a different location in memory using GDB?`